# match 2 properties' values in array of objects and filter matches based on a 3rd property's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I've got a graph with nodes that can be connected to multiple other nodes.

Every node represents an object in an array. Within every node's object is an array that contains the ids of all the nodes linked to this node and its depth:

```
 nodes: [
    {"id":1, "depth":0, "next":[], "children":[2, 3]},     // nodes.next = [2, 3]
    {"id":2, "depth":1, "next":[], "children":[1, 4, 5]},  // nodes.next = [4, 5]
    {"id":3, "depth":1, "next":[], "children":[1, 6, 7]},  // nodes.next = [6, 7]
    {"id":4, "depth":2, "next":[], "children":[2, 8]},     // nodes.next = [8]
    {"id":5, "depth":2, "next":[], "children":[2, 9]}      // nodes.next = [9]
]
```

I would like to traverse the graph from a certain node.

The problem is that a node's children array contains **all** the nodes linked to it. A node with a depth of 2 points back to a node with a depth of 1.

So I would like to create a new array within the nodes' objects, let's say `nodes.next` and get rid of the children that point back to a node that has a depth lower than itself.

The part that really baffles me is checking the depth of the nodes in `nodes.children`. I even haven't been near the part where I might check if the depth of a node in `nodes.children` is higher than `nodes[i].depth` and push `nodes[i].children[i]` to `nodes[i].next`.

If there is better way to solve this problem I'd be happy to know. My attemps have been fruitless in many ways alike:

```
let childDepth;
for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    for (let child in nodes[i].children) {
        if (nodes.id === child) {
            childDepth = nodes[i].depth;
        }
        if (childDepth > graph.nodes[i].depth) {
            nodes[i].next.push(child)
        }
    }
}
```

Updated array:

```
const nodes = [
    { "id": 37, "depth": 0, "children": [210, 395, 265], "next": [] },
    { "id": 210, "depth": 1, "children": [37, 260, 259, 391],"next": [] },
    { "id": 256, "depth": 2, "children": [265], "next": [] },
    { "id": 259, "depth": 2, "children": [210, 397, 396], "next": [] },
    { "id": 260, "depth": 2, "children": [210], "next": [] },
    { "id": 265, "depth": 1, "children": [37, 256, 388, 394, 271, 269], "next": [] },
    { "id": 269, "depth": 2, "children": [265], "next": [] },
    { "id": 271, "depth": 2, "children": [265], "next": [] },
    { "id": 388, "depth": 2, "children": [265], "next": [] },
    { "id": 391, "depth": 2, "children": [210], "next": [] },
    { "id": 394, "depth": 2, "children": [265], "next": [] },
    { "id": 395, "depth": 1, "children": [37], "next": [] },
    { "id": 396, "depth": 3, "children": [259, 413], "next": [] },
    { "id": 397, "depth": 3, "children": [259], "next": [] },
    { "id": 413, "depth": 4, "children": [396], "next": [] }
];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Kindly take a look on the below code to see if it's what you're looking for

```
const array = [
  {id:1, depth:0, next:[], children:[2, 3]},
  {id:2, depth:1, next:[], children:[1, 4, 5]},  
  {id:3, depth:1, next:[], children:[1, 6, 7]},  
  {id:4, depth:2, next:[], children:[2, 8]},    
  {id:5, depth:2, next:[], children:[2, 9]}
]

array.forEach(x => {
  let { children, depth } = x;

  for(let i=depth; i< children.length; i++){
    x.next.push(children[i]);
  }
});
```

Output as below:

```
[
  {"id":1,"depth":0,"next":[2,3],"children":[2,3]},
  {"id":2,"depth":1,"next":[4,5],"children":[1,4,5]}, 
  {"id":3,"depth":1,"next":[6,7],"children":[1,6,7]}, 
  {"id":4,"depth":2,"next":[],"children":[2,8]},
  {"id":5,"depth":2,"next":[],"children":[2,9]}
]
```

Comment: I've removed the extra variable and using destructuring to further enhanced the code. Cheers

Comment: There's a situation in which your solution doesn't seem to work. I updated the question with another array. `id: 396` has two children so one of them defenitly should be pushed to `next`, but that isn't happening. Do you know why?

Comment: `{ "id": 396, "depth": 3`. Depth is 3 and your children only two. Why will it be push to next?

Comment: Because the depth of one of the children, the one with `id:413`, is higher than `id:396` own depth. So `id:413` should be pushed to `id:396` next array. I see that it doesn't happen because `i > children.length`. I realized that you can also check if `children.length > 1`, then push all the children except the one at index 0 to next. But that's not really nice. The child with a depth lower then the current node coincidently always happens to be at index 0.

Comment: I added a picture of a graph for the nodes array. The orange node is the root. The yellow node is the child not pushed to `id:413` next array

Comment: I got it working, I would really appreciate it if you would have a look at how to improve the code. It's so ugly..

Comment: @Vincent: Sure, have you included the code that you've written? Is it the double for loop?